# Spring ModelAndView not working with ajax call

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, modelandview

Ajax calls a Spring Controller ***employee_edit*** but the ModelAndView is not working. It does not redirect to jsp page with object.I want to redirect to the page ***employee_registration.jsp*** with the object ***employee***. Code has no error.

**Ajax**

```
 $('#example1 tbody').on( 'click', 'button1', function () {
                var eid = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data().eid;
                $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url:"employee_edit?eid="+eid
                });
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/employee_edit", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView RegitrationEdit(@RequestParam("eid") long eid)
{           
  Employee employee=employeeService.getEmployee(eid);
  ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView(); 
  mv.setViewName("employee/employee_registration");
  mv.addObject("employee",employee);
  return mv;
}
```

After running the code it does not show any error. Going through the  code `ModelAndView("employee/employee_registration","employee",employee);` but nothing happens. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"employee/employee_registration"` page is located in `resources/templates/employee/employee_registration.jsp` right? And btw do you use spring-boot or just spring with custom configs?

Comment: @varren Thank you for your reply.Page path and all are OK. Its working on the controller `@RequestMapping("/employee")
 public String Employee()
 {
  return "employee/employee_registration";
  
 }` and using Spring MVC not Spring Boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your ajax call you need to add the success parameter. You can simply modify your call as

```
 $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"employee_edit",
            data:{"eid":eid},
            success:function(data){
            }
       });
```

or you can also add only the success parameter in your code

```
$.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"employee_edit?eid="+eid
            success:function(data) { }
       });
```

But I prefer the first one. Its more clear.

This should complete the ajax call and your program should work.

Answer (score 0):

When calling from ajax, ModelAndView will not work. You need to return the employee object as json by marking the the return type with annotation `@ResponseBody`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/employee_edit", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Employee RegitrationEdit(@RequestParam("eid") long eid)
{           
  Employee employee=employeeService.getEmployee(eid);    
  return employee;
}
```

After that upon successful call, you will get the response inside success callback.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"employee_edit?eid="+eid,
    success: function(data) {
        //here data is the employee object
        //process it here and redirect using window.location
    }
});
```